# How to get the values of multiple textFields in UITableView with dynamic cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a UIViewController I have a UITableView with 1 Dynamic Prototype cell of class type `TextInputTableViewCell`.
 In the Content View of the prototype cell I am adding a textField.

1. How can I populate the text fields with data from userInfo?
2. How can I get the data of each textField once they are edited by the user?

I have read on SO that I should use tags, but others said that this method is *prone to bugs and fragile*. Anyway, I don't know how to get the data from the fields using tags or other method. Please advise.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

 class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{ 
      @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

     //closure when the text changes
     var textChangedCallBack: ((_ cell: TextInputTableViewCell, _ text:String) -> ())?
      //Delegate method called when the text field loses focus
     func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textChangedCallBack?(self,textField.text!)
  }
}//end of class TextInputTableViewCell



class EditProfile: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {

 var dbRef:FIRDatabaseReference! //create a reference to Firebase
 var userInfo = [FireBaseData]() //this array will hold all data under userType in Firebase



@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBAction func saveToFirebase(_ sender: Any) {  

 //will post data from text fields  to firebase
}


struct Item {
    var name:String
    var editable:Bool
}

let placeHolderItems = [
    Item(name: "Name", editable: false),
    Item(name: "Phone Number", editable: true),
    Item(name: "Email", editable: true),
    Item(name: "Flat Number", editable: true),
    Item(name: "Street Address", editable: true),
    Item(name: "Postcode", editable: true)
]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Cleaners")
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(true)

   //get user's profile from firebase
    self.startObservingDB { (userProfile) in

        if userProfile.count > 0 {
            self.userInfo = userProfile
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return placeHolderItems.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell

    cell.textField.isEnabled = placeHolderItems[indexPath.row].editable
    cell.textField.placeholder = placeHolderItems[indexPath.row].name

 //After viewWillAppear finishes, self.userInfo will have the profile of
 //the user. How can I get here each textField  of the tableView so I can
   //populate each one of them with data from  self.userInfo?



         if !self.userInfo.isEmpty{

switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
         cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].FirstName + " " + self.userInfo[indexPath.row].LastName
    case 1:
        cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].PhoneNumber

    case 2: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].EmailAddress

    case 3: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].FlatNumber

    case 4: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].StreetAddress

    case 5: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].PostCode

    default:
        break
     }
 }


    cell.textChangedCallBack = {(cell, text) in

        //get the cell's current index path 
        if let path = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

            //get the item at that row
            var item = self.placeHolderItems[path.row]

            //update the item with the new name  
        }  
    }

    return cell
  }
 }//end of EditProfileclass





extension EditProfile {


  //get user's profile in order to populate it in tableView
   func startObservingDB(callback:@escaping ((_ snapShot: [FireBaseData]) -> Void)) {

    //check if user is singed in
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid  else {
        return
    }  

    dbRef.child(uid).child("profile").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var profileData = [FireBaseData]()

        for keyVal in snapshot.children{

            let userData = FireBaseData(snapshot: keyVal as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            profileData.append(userData)
                       }
        callback(profileData)

    }, withCancel: { (Error:Any) in 
        print("error is \(Error as! String)")

    })
    dbRef.removeAllObservers()

}//end of startObserving

}//end of EditProfile Class
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can subclass the UITextField and add the indexPath, then set it on the cellForRowAt method.

Comment: @Kerberos No, do not do that. That is a very bad solution.

Comment: @rmaddy really?? And how do you get back the textfield position from tableview? Every advice is more than helpful.

Comment: @rmaddy I assume that you deleted your answer because of my last comment at your answer. I apologize. I wanted to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, but I haven’t read your answer... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual problem to be solved is: The user has a edited a text field in a table view cell, and now we want to update the *data model* accordingly. But *which* cell contains this text field?

The notion "which" really means: what is the index path represented by the containing cell? If we knew that, we could easily update the model, because if our table view data source is correctly designed, we already know how to access the model by means of the index path.

So what I do is simply walk up the view hierarchy from the text field to the cell, and then ask the table view what index path this cell represents. This is a commonly used pattern in my apps:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    var v : UIView = textField
    repeat { v = v.superview! } while !(v is UITableViewCell)
    let cell = v as! MyCell // or UITableViewCell or whatever
    let ip = self.tableView.indexPath(for:cell)!
    // and now we have the index path! update the model
}
```

Comment: `repeat { v = v.superview! } while !(v is UITableViewCell)` my understanding of this block of code  is: as long as the `textField` is not of type `UITableViewCell`, then `var v` will be assigned the `superView` of the `textField`. I thought that the superView of the textField was the ContentView, thus when you do `let cell = v as! MyCell` we might not get `MyCell`, but actually the `ContentView` of the `textField`. I am using your code and it works. I just want to understand it better. Thanks

Comment: @bibscy That is why we `repeat`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInputCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell

    cell.textField.isEnabled = placeHolderItems[indexPath.row].editable
    cell.textField.placeholder = placeHolderItems[indexPath.row].name


    if !self.userInfo.isEmpty{

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].FirstName + " " + self.userInfo[indexPath.row].LastName
        case 1:
            cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].PhoneNumber

        case 2: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].EmailAddress

        case 3: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].FlatNumber

        case 4: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].StreetAddress

        case 5: cell.textField.text = self.userInfo[0].PostCode

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // Add tag to cell textField as cell current index
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
    //Observer changes as user edits
    cell.txtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)

    return cell
}

//MARK: - TextField Delegate
func textFieldDidChange(textfield: UITextField) {
    print("TextField \(String(describing: textfield.text)) Tag : \(textfield.tag)")

    switch textfield.tag {
    case 0:
        let Name  = textfield.text // or store where ever you want in sepearte array or update in userInfo
    case 1:
        let PhoneNumber   = textfield.text

    case 2:
        let EmailAddress   = textfield.text

    case 3:
        let FlatNumber   = textfield.text

    case 4:
        let StreetAddress   = textfield.text

    case 5:
        let PostCode  = textfield.text
    default:
        break
    }

}

// Don't forget to add UITextFieldDelegate
```

Comment: What is the purpose to create a `String` from a `String` (`textfield.text`)? Do not use the `describing` initializer anyway unless you really need it for example to get the string description of a point like `String(describing: CGPoint.zero)`